# Is there a name for this type of construction?

Tags: phrases, expressions, construction

2-part question:

(1) Is there a name for this type of construction in English?

Examples:

"We can't go, can we?"

"I am here, aren't I?"

"We mustn't get ahead of ourselves, must we?"

"You are going, aren't you?"

The basic construction involves making a statement, and then asking the negation. So is there a name for this?

(2) Is this construction unique to English?

Comment: This exists in French, too, _n'est-ce pas_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are "**question tags**" (BrE) or "**tail questions**" or "**tag questions**" (AmE)

> [**Question tags**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/grammar-reference/question-tags) are the short questions that we put on the end of sentences – particularly in spoken English.

If you are interested in the rules (they are very easy to learn) just follow the above link.

And yes, they do exist in several european languages. (French, Spanish, Portuguese, etc)